# Neo4j: Invalid Username and Password

Tags: authentication, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j. Just installed it and started the browser and I get the "Invalid username and password error" when I enter neo4j/neo4j for username/password.

Comment: Try shift-reload to clear the browser caches or clear the cache in the inspector (disable cache, reload, enable cache).

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to a [known issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4012). To quote from a comment in that issue:

> Yes, this is due to aggressive web browser caching. Refresh the page
>   so you get an uncached version and it should work as expected.